# Vista 2 administrator account disabled for repair

Tags: windows-vista, bios, system-restore

Vista service pack 2 ...

I can:

Turn on computer
Listen to unending beeps
Get into BIOS
See that boot is set to 1. CD/DVD 2. USB 3 hard drive
Load defaults

I cannot:

Save defaults

I can:

Reboot
Press escape
Select hard drive
Log in as administrator
Restart
f8
Select repair
Select keyboard

I cannot:
Get past administrator password check: "your administration account has been disabled"

I can:

Reboot
run Malwarebytes, Avast
Disable all unknown plugins and services

But:
Still no admin account in repair

Hmmmm ....

If it's MBR or some such why can I get admin in safe and normal mode, but not repair? If that betrays my ignoranc

What to do, what to do

*fingers thrumming*

Comment: If you cannot even modify your BIOS then your computer has problems we likely cannot solve.  Have you tried to reinstall Windows?  There are guides that exist that explain how to enable the Administrator account, but the problem is rooted deeper, the fact you cannot save your BIOS configuration is a hardware problem.

Comment: Why would you want to load default settings in BIOS? Do you have a password in BIOS? Can you log on into normal Windows mode? Is Windows even booting?... Are you actually trying to boot from the Windows Vista DVD (a.k.a. WinRE)?

Answer (score 0):

The Administrator account is disabled by default in Windows Vista. You need to enable it first before you can use it. If you can log into normal Windows mode, you can enable the Administrator account.

**Enable Administrator account**

1. Start Windows in normal mode and log on.
2. Run lusrmgr.msc
3. Click on "Users" folder on the left.
4. Right click on the Administrator account on the left and click Properties.
5. Under the General tab, uncheck "Account is disabled". Also, "Password never expires" should be checked. All other options should be unchecked by default.
6. Click OK to save.
7. Close the Local Users and Groups window.

This applies to all administrator accounts, not only the Administrator account. The Administrator account is a built-in administrative account in Windows XP, Vista and above. Any user account listed in the Administrators group is an administrator.

**To view all administrator accounts available**

1. Start Windows in normal mode and log on.
2. Run lusrmgr.msc
3. Click on Groups on the left.
4. Right click on Administrators and click Properties.
5. Under "Members" you will see all administrator accounts (members of administrators group).

If you have forgotten the password for any of the user accounts, you can use the same tool to set a new password.

**To set a new password for an admin account**

1. Start Windows in normal mode and log on.
2. Run lusrmgr.msc
3. Click on "Users" folder on the left.
4. Right click on an administrator account and click on "Set password".
5. Read the warning and click on Proceed. You will be asked to set a new password for this account.

If you can't log on to Windows in normal mode, then you will have to either reinstall Windows or look for a way to recover the lost password. There are several methods, and several utilities you can use for this, both official Windows tools and commercial software products.

If your problem lies with BIOS, e.g. not being able to make changes or save changes, i.e. if you have a BIOS password that prevents you from doing this, then you will have to clear the CMOS.